# 2020 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Drones and Model Aircraft's [first moderator election](https://drones.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the three new moderators are:

[image: ifconfig] [image: Daniil] [image: Jacob B] 
Please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://drones.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5206745230082048/0).

Comment: Congrats, these guys'll make a great team!

Answer (score 6):

Congratulations *ifconfig* and *Jacob B*. I look forward to working with you closely.

A big thank you to the other candidates: *gparyani*, *Kralc* and *Kenn Sebesta*. Without you, this election would not have been possible.

Also a big thank you also to all the [38 users who voted](https://drones.stackexchange.com/help/badges/81/constituent).

Comment: +1 I strongly second this comment. (*is that a thing someone can even do? lol*)

Comment: I second ifconfig's second as well as seconding Daniil's answer. :)  Thank you to everyone who participated; candidates and voters.

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations to all three of you. I'm not an active contributor, but rather a heavy reader and participant on MSE.

Your actions on the site have been instrumental in the site's initial launch. You took charge and lead by example, reviewing and editing when necessary, and actively participated on Meta.

I hope none of that changes as you move into your new role. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Well done folks - as a mod team I think you will do very well growing and directing this site. I'm not very active here, but definitely interested, and hopefully will get more time once summer arrives.